# Understanding Part and Span operating on expressions with heads that are not List

Tags: list-manipulation, core-language

I hope this is not a duplicate. I do not understand how does the `Part` and `Span` functions work on this expression:

```
g = f[a, b, c];
```

Taking zeroth element we get head

```
g[[0]]
(* => f *)
```

First, second and third element would give `a`, `b` and `c` respectively

```
g[[1]]
(* => a *)
g[[2]]
(* => b *)
g[[3]]
(* => c *)
```

My aim was to take second and third elements of `f`'s arguments as a list. But

```
g[[2;;3]]
(* => f[b, c] *)
```

and I'm confused (the same with `g[[{2, 3}]]`). As a reslut I would expect expression with `List` or `Sequence` head instead. Why do we get this reslut? Is it consistent with that `g[[1]]` doesn't give `f[1]`?

Comment: `Part` retains the head of an original expression, when given a list of positions to extract, rather than a single position. The same with `Span`, which is conceptually the same as a list of positions.

Comment: So my confusion comes from the fact that for expressions with `List` heads  `Part` would give expression with the same head (=`List`).

Comment: But what about `g[[1]]` vs `g[[{1}]]`?

Comment: `Extract[g, {{2}, {3}}]` gives `{b,c}`

Comment: `g[[1]] === Part[g, 1]` is a *single* element extraction, so the element itself is returned. `g[[{1}]] === Part[g,{1}]` is an extraction of a list of elements, which happen to be just one element. In that case, you effectively get `Head[g][sequence-of-extracted-elements]`. With `Association`s, this is similar (although not quite the same) - there you get back an `Association` with extracted key-value pairs, if you use `assoc[[{parts}]]`.

Comment: @eldo ... which is equivalent to `{Part[g, 2], Part[f[a, b, c], 3]}`, thanks!

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Thank you. It sounds like an answer to me, but why `Head[g]` instead of `List` (pure curiosity)?

Comment: @mmal It makes sense. If you want to extract a sequence of parts, you want to group them into some container. Grouping them into original head rather than a `List` means that you create an "object" similar to the original one, but with fewer parts. This is much more useful behavior in a large number of cases, than if the parts would have been grouped always in a `List`. And if you want the latter behavior, it is always easy to get by `Apply`-ing `List` to the result.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Thank you once again. Yes... it makes sense and your comments answer my questions. If there is no further interest I may delete it or accept your answer.

Comment: @mmal Was glad to help. I added this as an answer.

Comment: similar: [(2449)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2449/142), [(95763)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/95763/142).

Comment: @WReach Thank you for pointing this out. I would say that it may even be duplicate of the former.

Comment: @WReach I wish I remembered about those posts, would make my answering unnecessary.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### General

`Part` retains the head of an original expression, when given a list of positions to extract, rather than a single position. The same with `Span`, which is conceptually the same as a list of positions.

```
Part[h[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 1]
Part[h[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], {3, 4, 5}]
Part[h[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3 ;; 5]

(* 
   1

   h[3, 4, 5]

   h[3, 4, 5]
*)
```

It makes sense. If you want to extract a sequence of parts, you want to group them into some container. Grouping them into original head rather than a List means that you create an "object" similar to the original one, but with fewer parts. This is much more useful behavior in a large number of cases, than if the parts would have been grouped always in a `List`. And if you want the latter behavior, it is always easy to get by `Apply` - ing `List` to the result.

#### Example: evaluation control

Here is just one (a bit artificial) example, where this is rather useful:

```
Part[Hold[1^2, 2^2, 3^2], 2]

(* 4 *)
```

but

```
Part[Hold[1^2, 2^2, 3^2], {2}]

(* Hold[2^2] *)
```

so in this case, this semantics of `Part` allowed us to prevent evaluation leak, if we wanted to.

#### The case of `Association`s

One case which stands out is that of `Associations`. We can start by noting a curious fact that `Association`s are atomic, and yet we can extract parts from them. In any case, the principle that the head of the expression is retained when several parts are extracted in a `List`, holds here too. Together with the head, the keys are also retained:

```
<|1 -> 2, 3 -> 4, 5 -> 6|>[[2]]

(* 4 *)
```

but

```
<|1 -> 2, 3 -> 4, 5 -> 6|>[[{2}]]

(* <|3 -> 4|> *)
```

and

```
<|1 -> 2, 3 -> 4, 5 -> 6|>[[{2, 3}]]

(* <|3 -> 4, 5 -> 6|> *)
```

This is in fact a very useful behavior of `Association`s, in a number of situations.

Comment: Thank you, a very good and understandable explanation

Comment: @eldo Glad you found it helpful.