# Why is Part designed to sometimes wrap the original head around the parts it extracts?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, core-language

For me, the natural meaning of the function `Part` is "get the sub-expression at appointing position." It is quite unlike `Take`, `Take` always keeps the head in the process. For example, by using `Take`:

```
Take[f[a, b, c[i], d[j, k], e, f], {3, 4}, 1]
(* Take the third to fourth position at level 1; and first position at level 2 *)
(* Output: f[c[i], d[j]] *)
```

When using `Part`:

```
Part[f[a, b, c[i], d[j, k], e, f], 4, 2]
(*Take the expression directly at the position 4, 2*)
(* Output: k *)
```

Until now, the mechanism of both functions is quite natural to me.
However, the next result leaves me feeling confused:

```
f[a, b, c[i], d[j, k], e, f][[4]]
f[a, b, c[i],d[j, k], e, f][[4;;5]]
```

The output is `d[j, k]` versus `f[d[j, k], e]`. I don't know why I get the latter result -- where the extracted parts are wrapped with `f`. I was expecting `{d[j, k], e}`.

Is this design reasonable or useful in most cases? What is its intended use?

Comment: It is documented in `ref/ Part` details section. And it can be useful `Hold[Print[1], Print[2]][[{1}]]`

Comment: @Kuba I just found that the usage of `Part[expr,{n}]` seems undocumented.

Comment: How is that undocumented? Isn't it the 4th usage? And see also the 4th bullet point in Details section.

Comment: Ya, but the document said "*gives a "list" of the parts $i_1,~i_2,~\cdots$ of expr.*" According to it, the result should be surrounded by the `{}`(namely, a list) right?

Comment: Oh I see. In the Details, they said more.

Comment: It might be worth comparing with `Extract[f[a, b, c[i], d[j, k], e, f], {{4}, {5}}]`.

Comment: As far as I always understood, things like `Part[expr, Span[__]]` and `Part[expr, All]` are basically syntactic sugar for invoking `Take`.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Do you prefer using `Take` instead of `Part[expr, List[__]]`?

Comment: [This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2449/81) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/99180/81) QAs seem relevant, if not duplicates.

Comment: @Eric Well, `Part[expr, List[__]]` is something you can't really do with `Take`. For example, there's no way to do `f[a,b,c,d,e][[{1, 2, 5}]]` with `Take`. As for personal preference: I actually prefer to stick with `Part` most of the time, except when I need `Take[list, UpTo[n]]` (which actually works with `Part` and `Span` as well, but is rather ugly).